# Fragment added in landscape mode still remains in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created an activity with one fragment in portrait mode and two fragments in landscape mode. When in portrait mode if i check

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment tt=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.one);
```

it returns null as expected since R.id.one is the id of the second Fragment. But when i shift mobile to landscape it shows the Fragment as expected and i am able to work on views of the fragment.
However if  i shift back from landscape to portrait it still finds fragment one but unable to work with its views.
Kindly update why it shows Fragment one when we come back from landscape to portrait and how to deal with it.

Comment: Please show full code of how you're creating and adding the Fragments to the Activity. Also "R.id.one is the id of the second Fragment" - reconsider your naming ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it seems that the issue you are experiencing may be related to the lifecycle of the Fragment and how it is being added to the Activity.

When you shift from portrait to landscape mode, the Activity is recreated, and the FragmentManager adds the two Fragments to the Activity. When you shift back to portrait mode, the Activity is recreated again, and the FragmentManager attempts to add both Fragments to the Activity. However, since only one Fragment is meant to be shown in portrait mode, the FragmentManager adds the first Fragment and ignores the second one.

To properly handle the lifecycle of Fragments in your Activity, you should create two separate layout files - one for portrait mode and one for landscape mode - and add the appropriate Fragment to each layout. This way, when the Activity is recreated, the FragmentManager will only add the relevant Fragment to the Activity. Here is an example of how you can accomplish this:

Create two layout files: one for portrait mode (e.g. activity_main.xml) and one for landscape mode (e.g. activity_main_land.xml).
activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

activity_main_land.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_two"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentTwo"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your Activity's onCreate() method, inflate the appropriate layout based on the device's orientation, and add the Fragment(s) to the Activity:
MainActivity.java:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragmentOne)
                .commit();
    } else {
        FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
        FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_one, fragmentOne)
                .add(R.id.fragment_two, fragmentTwo)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

With this approach, when you shift from portrait to landscape mode, the FragmentManager adds both Fragments to the Activity, and when you shift back to portrait mode, the FragmentManager only adds the relevant Fragment to the Activity. Additionally, since the Fragment is added directly to the layout, you can access its views using findViewById() instead of relying on the FragmentManager.

Comment: Since we have already added fragments in the layout why we need to add them through the fragmentmanager again. I have the same layout as you have shown. One fragment in portrait and 2 fragments in landscape. When the activity shows in portrait it shows the one fragment. when i shift from portrait to landscape it shows two fragments. but now if i shift back to portrait i am able to find the second fragment using fragmentmanager.findfragmentbyid. this is the query why fragmentmanager is not returning null for second fragment in portrait mode

Comment: When you shift from portrait mode to landscape mode, the activity is recreated, and the system creates the two fragments specified in the landscape layout. However, when you shift back from landscape to portrait mode, the activity is not recreated, and the system simply hides the landscape fragments and shows the portrait fragment.